# Using json function with a string in vb.net

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

When I try to send back a json string with the following json function the string is inserts new lines and escapes characters in vb.net.

Questions

1. How do I get it to return as proper json?
2. Is it possible to use something like Json(data:=jsonstr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) to fix the issue?
3. Is it possible to use notation similar to C# when dealing with Json strings? Dim someJson as string= @"{""firstname"":"+c.c_firstname+"}"

-

```
Function get_people_jsonresult(Optional id As Integer = 0) As JsonResult
Dim c As dtb_people = db.dtb_people.Where(Function(x) x.c_Id = 1).Single
Dim jsonstr As String = "{
""firstname"":""" + c.c_firstname + """,
""lastname"":""" + c.c_lastname + """,
""id"":" + c.c_Id.ToString + "
}"
Return Json(jsonstr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

Returned string

```
"[{\r\n                \"firstname\":\"john\",\r\n                \"lastname\":\"smith\",\r\n                \"id\":1\r\n                }]"
```

**updated:**
The idea is to figure out different ways to do the same thing to figure out a style that I like.

1) I found this solution but kind of quirky but makes sense - i.e. turn it into an object it will recognize vs. something generic like Ctype(jsonstr, object). I think the point is that jsonresult is meant to serialize json, but this is already serialized, so it should be returned as is.

```
Dim d As Dictionary(Of String, String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(jsonstr)
Return Json(d, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

2) Still not sure if something like this is possible

3) It doesn't look like @ offers any benefit since vb.net does multi-line string literals an optional format could be a string interpolation and to use single quotes vs. double so there is no need to escape them.

```
Dim jsonstr2 As String = $"{{
    'firstname': '{c.c_firstname}',
    'lastname':'{c.c_lastname}' ,
    'id':{c.c_Id.ToString} 
}}"
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Json () function accepts an object as the first parameter. It is not expecting a json string.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the dtb_people object instead of building the string as below:

```
Return Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

The returned Json will use whatever the property names of your dtb_people class are

If you are wanting to use different property names in your Json, you would decorate your dtb_people class with a JsonProperty declaration and set the PropertyName to whatever you want

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstname")]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question which was why it was inserting VBCrLf is because you made a string with some carriage return. Having your string like this on multiple lines will make a string VBCrLf inside it. But @Darthchai has the answer to make your Json

[image: look here]